# jQuery cycle2 - fade/fadout content overlap issue

Tags: jquery, html, css, slider, fade

Please checkout [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qLQv5/)

```
<div class="right-panel">
        <div class="cycle-slideshow testimonials"
        data-cycle-fx="fadeout"
         data-cycle-speed=3500
         data-cycle-timeout=1000
         data-cycle-slides="> blockquote"
        >
```

How to avoid content overlapping issue when slider fadeIn/Out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content overlapping is happening because of the slow animation speed (data-cycle-speed). The extra reason you are seeing the overlap is because of the lack of a background of the blockquote elements. I updated your fiddle so that the animation is faster en the blockquote has a background color: http://jsfiddle.net/veritas87/qLQv5/1/

You can set the rotation speed (how long slides are staying on screen) with the data-cycle-timeout:

```
data-cycle-speed=500
data-cycle-timeout=3000
```

Answer (score 2):

Can try this..[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qLQv5/3/)

A few updates been made in html.

```
.right-panel div{
background:#fff;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/Mbs46/

```
.right-panel blockquote{
background-color:#fff;
    height:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is caused by the [`sync`](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/api/) option with its default value of `true` in combination with your setting of the `fx` option to `fadeout`.

**From the jQuery Cycle2 API docs:**

> **sync:** If `true` then animation of the incoming and outgoing slides will be
>   synchronized. If `false` then the animation for the incoming slide will
>   not start until the animation for the outgoing slide completes.

There is no description provided for the `fadeout` transition, but observation indicates that it does just that: fades out. This is in contrast to the default crossfade behaviour which fades the initial slide out and the new slide in. I would have thought using `fadeout` would be fine: expected behaviour (with `sync` set to `false`) would be that the initial slide would fade out and only when finished would the new slide "pop" into appearance. Instead, the new slide appears at the same time that the fadeout begins.

What I would do is let Cycle2 perform its default crossfade effect and set the `sync` option to `false`. Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/indieweb/b56y1hdg/) to demonstrate.

You will note that adding a background to the slides is not required.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="right-panel">
    <div class="cycle-slideshow testimonials"
        data-cycle-speed=3500
        data-cycle-timeout=1000
        data-cycle-slides="&gt; blockquote"
        data-cycle-sync="false">
        <blockquote>
            <p>Moving Permits is an absolutely essential service for lorem ipsum dolor sit amet manga aliqua.</p>
            <cite>- John Doe</cite>
        </blockquote>
        <blockquote>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p>
            <cite>- John Doe</cite>
        </blockquote>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Note:** I encoded `>` as `&gt;` in the above HTML because SO incorrectly sees it as a closing tag. You are fine to use `>` in your actual HTML. (Here's an [SO question that addresses this specifically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9010678/html-should-i-encode-greater-than-or-not-gt)).