# Python parsing html with lxml: get text of tag while specific sign causes problems

Tags: python, html, lxml, lxml.html

I'm parsing Real-World HTML files with lxml. This means, I want to extract information from tags and I don't have the control of the style.
The problem I'm having lies within the data.

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>
    <strong>Notes</strong>
  </legend>
  Slav *kǫda 'thither', kǫdě   'where, whither' < IE *k(w)om-d(h) 
</fieldset>
```

The problem is due to the sign < within the data, the HTML parser of lxml will skip the text and the endtag, but this is exactly the text I want to extract.
Is there any solution I can apply to get the text out of this tag?

Answer (score 1):

The HTML is actually a [broken one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9010678/html-should-i-encode-greater-than-or-not-gt).

You can though parse it as is with [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) and a lenient `html5lib` parser:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


data = u"""
<fieldset>
  <legend>
    <strong>Notes</strong>
  </legend>
  Slav *kǫda 'thither', kǫdě   'where, whither' < IE *k(w)om-d(h)
</fieldset>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html5lib")
print(soup.fieldset.legend.next_sibling.strip())
```

Prints:

```
Slav *kǫda 'thither', kǫdě   'where, whither' < IE *k(w)om-d(h)
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I thought about using beautiful soup too. Is it really a broken html or is it just a letter which the html parser cannot parse?