# Glide JS data-glide-dir next is not being rendered correctly

Tags: glidejs

I use Glide JS for a Slideshow that I built with ACF and Gutenberg Blocks.

But there is an issue with the next button. The ">" does not get rendered correctly – and it destroyes the whole DOM. Is there an alternative for the "data-glide-dir" next command? When i remove the data-glide-dir=">" everything works just fine.

Below is the code I use – the screenshot shows how it finally gets rendered in the browser.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9dFL.png)

```html
<?php $gallery = get_field('images'); ?>
<?php if( $gallery ) : ?>

    <div class="gcont">

        <div class="glide">

            <div class="glide__track" data-glide-el="track">
                <ul class="glide__slides">
                <?php foreach( $gallery as $image ) : ?>
                    <li class="glide__slide"><img class="full-width-image" src="<?php echo esc_url($image['sizes']['large']); ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_attr($image['alt']); ?>"></li>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="glide__arrows" data-glide-el="controls">
                <button class="glide__arrow glide__arrow--prev" data-glide-dir="<">prev</button>
                <button class="glide__arrow glide__arrow--next" data-glide-dir=">">next</button>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 4):

What did the trick for me was encoding < with `&lt;` and > with `&gt;`

See also: [HTML: Should I encode greater than or not? ( > &gt; )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9010678/html-should-i-encode-greater-than-or-not-gt)